# generation of self-referential immutable types in Julia

Tags: julia

Julia lang documentation explains how inner constructors and the new() function can be used to construct self-referential objects:

```
  type SelfReferential
      obj::SelfReferential
      SelfReferential() = (x = new(); x.obj = x)
    end
```

However this approach does not work for immutable types, because it essentially uses mutation of the incompletely initialized instance x.

How can I generate a self-referential immutable object in Julia?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question -  you can't.

Comment: Moreover, why would you want to?

Comment: @David, to create performant, immutable recursive data structures. The only way I know to do this is via abstract types which should come at a performance penalty.  What I don't understand what in the concept of immutability of a type should prohibit a self-referential immutable?

Comment: Why does the recusive data structure need to be able to recurse directly it itself?

Comment: @Oxinabox Right, it doesn't need to do. I was thinking in this direction because recursion to itself is the way suggested in Julia documentation for mutable types. From the documentation it was not obvious to me that this is not possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you seemed to have used Haskell before, I will tailor this answer from a functional programming perspective. A common use case of self-referential immutable types is in creating a lazy list.

As a strict (i.e. not lazy) language, it is not possible for an immutable object to directly reference itself.

This does not preclude, however, referencing itself indirectly, using a mutable object like a `Ref` or `Vector`.

For the particular case of lazy structures, I might recommend confining the mutability to a special object, say, `Lazy{T}`. For instance,

```
import Base: getindex
type Lazy
    thunk
    value
    Lazy(thunk) = new(thunk)
end

evaluate!(lazy::Lazy) = (lazy.value = lazy.thunk(); lazy.value)
getindex(lazy::Lazy) = isdefined(lazy, :value) ? lazy.value : evaluate!(lazy)
```

Then, for instance, it's possible to make a simple lazy list as follows:

```
import Base: first, tail, start, next, done, iteratorsize, HasLength, SizeUnknown
abstract List
immutable Cons <: List
    head
    tail::Lazy
end
immutable Nil <: List end

macro cons(x, y)
    quote
        Cons($(esc(x)), Lazy(() -> $(esc(y))))
    end
end

first(xs::Cons) = xs.head
tail(xs::Cons) = xs.tail[]
start(xs::Cons) = xs
next(::Cons, xs) = first(xs), tail(xs)
done(::List, ::Cons) = false
done(::List, ::Nil) = true
iteratorsize(::Nil) = HasLength()
iteratorsize(::Cons) = SizeUnknown()
```

Which indeed works as it would in a language like Haskell:

```
julia> xs = @cons(1, ys)
Cons(1,Lazy(false,#3,#undef))

julia> ys = @cons(2, xs)
Cons(2,Lazy(false,#5,#undef))

julia> [take(xs, 5)...]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 1
 2
 1
```

This functionality may seem complex, but it luckily has already been implemented in [Lazy.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/Lazy.jl).

---

It is important to note that the above code creates a lot of overhead due to type instability and mutable types. If your goal in using `immutable` was not expressiveness, but rather performance, then obviously such an approach is not appropriate. But it is in general not possible to have a stack-allocated structure that references itself, so in cases where you want maximal performance, it's best to avoid self-reference entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I was exactly concerned about performance. The approach that you suggest is very similar to the PersistentList in FunctionalCollections.jl. However it implies the use of abstract types, and running @code_warntype with such code, shows me a lot of red warnings, aka Union{Cons,Nil}, so I am worried about performance. But your last sentence that self-reference is not possible in a stack-allocated structure explains it to me.

Comment: @Bernd Lists can actually be made very performant (though lazy lists less so). The way to define a performant list is to use `typealias List{T} Nullable{Cons{T}}`, which avoids the type instability.

Comment: If you want lists to be both performant and self-referential, then simply use `type` instead of `immutable`.